# Cannot get basic Content interface example working with Snapcraft

Tags: snap

I have been trying to get the `content` interface working with a trivial example.

consumer:

```
name: consumer # you probably want to 'snapcraft register <name>'
version: '0.1' # just for humans, typically '1.2+git' or '1.3.2'
summary: Single-line elevator pitch for your amazing snap # 79 char long summary
description: |

grade: devel # must be 'stable' to release into candidate/stable channels
confinement: devmode # use 'strict' once you have the right plugs and slots

apps:
  consumer:
    command: ls -lR /snap/consumer/current/

parts:
  my-part:
    # See 'snapcraft plugins'
    plugin: nil

plugs:
  shared-files:
    content: shared-files
    interface: content
    target: shared
    default-provider: provider:shared-files
```

provider:

```
name: provider # you probably want to 'snapcraft register <name>'
version: '0.1' # just for humans, typically '1.2+git' or '1.3.2'
summary: Single-line elevator pitch for your amazing snap # 79 char long summary
description: |

grade: devel # must be 'stable' to release into candidate/stable channels
confinement: devmode # use 'strict' once you have the right plugs and slots

parts:
  my-part:
    plugin: dump
    source: .

slots:
  shared-files:
    content: shared-files
    interface: content
    read:
    - /src
```

`/src` has some random files placed in it. I can see these in `/snap/provider/current` but nowhere in the `/snap/consumer/current` tree - which is where I believe they should appear.
`snap interfaces` shows that the plug and slot are connected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You're so close!

The content sharing interface bind-mounts the slot to the plug's target. To that end, the `target` parameter must be pointing to an existing directory (bind mounts need to mount on top of something just like any other mount). So in your `consumer`, instead of using the `nil` plugin, use the `dump` plugin and dump an empty `shared` directory into the root of the snap. Then you'll see `provider`'s `$SNAP/src` directory show up in `consumer`'s `$SNAP/shared` directory.

Note that you won't see this from the system perspective. If you `ls /snap/consumer/current/shared/` from the system, it'll be the empty directory you packaged into the snap. However, when an application is fired up, the context in which it is run contains that bind mount. Let me prove it:

```
$ snap run --shell consumer
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

$ ls $SNAP/shared/
file1  file2
```

`snap run --shell` runs a shell within the exact environment that would be used for the application in question. So running `snap run --shell consumer` you're asking for a shell with the same confinement and environment that the `consumer` app would have. That's why I could use `$SNAP` there. Note that `file1` and `file2` are the files contained within my `provider`'s `src` directory.

One last note: assuming that you want the `consumer` app to list the contents of the shared directory, you would change it to look like this (no need to use /snap/consumer/current):

```
apps:
  consumer:
    command: ls -lR $SNAP/shared/
```

Comment: One issue with that approach is that you won't be able to provide a read-write directory to the consuming snap. It seems that snapd passes MS_RDONLY if the target directory is on a read-only file system which is the case with squashfs. This is not a required option though. http://paste.ubuntu.com/24336824/

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that should be the case. That strace is coming from `snap-confine`? Might be worth logging a bug.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is coming from snap-confine/mount-support.c https://paste.ubuntu.com/24339585/ : 

7 mount-support.c        sc_setup_mount_profiles     228 int flags = MS_BIND | MS_RDONLY | MS_NODEV | MS_NOSUID;

Comment: https://pad.lv/1681068 - filed a bug.